# How to convert java String to ObjectId of mongodb _id using java programming language

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

e.g:

```
String hexString = "5afea3b5bc7f8d04fc61d525";
```

to an `ObjectId` like

```
ObjectId("5afea3b5bc7f8d04fc61d525")
```

Here the above string is obtained from objectId so while writing query in mongodb the _id of mongodb document doesnot match to the string.....Therefore how can i get the matched data from mongodb document by passing string as parameter from rest api to match that _id of mongodb document.

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
ObjectId objId = new ObjectId("5afea3b5bc7f8d04fc61d525");
```

See more `ObjectId` constructor [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html)

Comment: But the string parameter should be hexadecimal. So,what should I do??????

Comment: What do you mean? Use new ObjectId to convert it. What's your problem?

Comment: public ResponseEntity<GpsAttribute> getQuickOverview(@PathVariable("trackerId") String trackerId),,,,Here i need to pass the trackerId as string but it is not recognized by mongodb beacuse the id in mongodb is bsonobject. Hence i need to pass the string so that it match as the _id of mongodb document.

Comment: What about `new ObjectId(trackerId)`? Do you have any problem calling that?

Comment: ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(trackerId);
        System.out.println("objectId:::::::::::::::::::::::"+objectId);    here the console shows as    objectId:::::::::::::::::::::::5afea3b5bc7f8d04fc61d525 but what i need is ObjectId("5afea3b5bc7f8d04fc61d525"); to be console

Comment: You pass that `ObjectId objectId` to your query. That's it.

Comment: well i am on it....And thanks for your answer.